# WAF code generation using multiple dependent input files

Tags: waf

How do I best use WAF (https://waf.io/) for the following scenario?

model1.m + model2.m --> Code Generator --> many .h & .cpp files --> compile

- model1.m and model2.m has to be processed together.
- Code generator is very slow and we should only generate/compile if the files has changed.

My current approach is to create a feature that supports the following.

```
def build(bld):
    bld.shlib(
        features='cxx gen_messaging', 
        name="messages",
        source='model1.m model2.m')
```

The feature is basically getting the model files from self.source and then run the code generation and lastly adding the new source to self.source.

What I am missing is to detect if the model files has changed. Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've done something like https://waf.io/book/#_mixing_extensions_and_c_c_features. This way it should work. But as you mentioned the requirement of models to be processed together, I suppose you have designed a specific Task class. In this case, you have to write code like https://waf.io/book/#_custom_tasks. The important point is the correct handling of signatures in the `run()` AND `runnable_status()` methods.